# Store different data of the same format in one table, or multiple tables of the same format?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, relations, eav

Consider I have the following MySQL tables:

**`products`**
id | created_at | updated_at | name | description | barcode

**`stores`**
id | created_at | updated_at | name | description | address

**`product_attributes`**
id | product_id | attribute_name | attribute_value

**`store_attributes`**
id | store_id | attribute_name | attribute_value

Note that the `product_attributes` and `store_attributes` tables are actually the same.
The application has the option to link attributes to products and stores in the form of a simple key-value form.
The `product_attributes` and `store_attributes` tables are used for this.

When a product is loaded, its attributes must be loaded too, and the same applies to stores.

There could also be just one table, say `attributes`, and then both the product attributes and the store attributes could be put in that `attributes` table together. Like as follows:

**`attributes`**
id | entity_id | attribute_name | attribute_value

I chose to keep the attribute data in separate tables as I thought it would have better performance when selecting data. However, I have no evidence that this assumption is correct.
When MySQL has to find all attributes for a given product_id, it has to look only in the `product_attributes` table, and it would never be scanning rows that don't belong to a product at all.
Is my design with separate tables (`product_attributes` and `store_attributes`) a better choice in terms of selection speed/performance?

Consider the design completely separate from any future adjustments or expansions. It's actually a very simplified example.

Comment: That choice will ultimately be the least of your problems and performance issues.  EAV is the main hassle, especially when you search by attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A table in a relational database isn't just a bucket of bytes into which any old value can be dumped. It is intended as the implementation of an entity type, which is a description of a class of things.

If your users consider store_attributes & product_attributes to be synonyms for the same class of things - they have the same provenance, life cycle, usage etc. - go ahead and combine them. If not keep them separate.